# How to use Entity in Column type (TypeORM)

Tags: postgresql, typescript, typeorm

I have a problem with TypeORM (Postgresql) Column types. I have an entity:

```
@Entity()
export class Destination {
    @Column({ type: 'varchar', array: true })
    addresses: string[];
```

I want this entity to be the type for Column in other entity (this entity should be like a phonebook - a lot of numbers but you choose only one - this one for other entity). What is the best way to do this? Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 0):

Before even talking about the TypeORM-specific implementation, I think what you are looking for is a many-to-one/one-to-many relation, right? 
If that's the case, then here's how to annotate such relation when defining TypeORM entities: [TypeORM docs](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations.md);

Answer (score 0):

example
`@ManyToOne(() => Question, (question) => question.constraints, {onDelete: 'CASCADE'}) question: Relation<Question>`

You just simply set type of Column to Destination

Comment: Do not post images of code. Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5031762

Comment: Ok, understood, thanks for advice